# Why does use of simple mat- control in Angular 2 Material (beta 11) project with no styling cause error with compatibility mode being needed?

Tags: angular-material2

I have a clean new project using **Angular Material 2** at **beta-11** level. This introduced the breaking changes around using the **mat-** prefix instead of the **md-** prefix for Material controls and styles.

I have no MaterialJS controls, and am not using any Material styles. This is just a very simple test of Material with a single `<mat-card></mat-card>` in my HTML.

The project fails at run time with an error telling me I am running in compatibility mode (why? I didn't ask to? I don't want to!) and so the mat- prefix can't be used.

I can remove the error and run OK by importing the AngularJS Compatibility Mode module (**NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode**) in my root module, but why do I need to do this given this is a new blank project with no compatibility needed?

This is the error I get if I **don't** import the compatibility mode module for my very simple "beta 11" test project.

```
**Uncaught (in promise): Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "mat-card" element.

    Error: The "mat-" prefix cannot be used in ng-material v1 compatibility mode. It was used on an "mat-card" element.
        at getMdCompatibilityInvalidPrefixError (core.es5.js:55)
        at new MatPrefixRejector (core.es5.js:76)
        at createClass (core.es5.js:10936)
        at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10764)
        at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12212)
        at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12661)
        at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12570)
        at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12239)
        at createRootView (core.es5.js:12107)
        at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13493)
        at getMdCompatibilityInvalidPrefixError (core.es5.js:55)
        at new MatPrefixRejector (core.es5.js:76)
        at createClass (core.es5.js:10936)
        at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10764)
        at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12212)
        at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12661)
        at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12570)
        at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12239)
        at createRootView (core.es5.js:12107)
        at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13493)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
        at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
        at zone.js:873
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
        at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
        at <anonymous>
    defaultErrorLogger @ core.es5.js:1020
    webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.es5.js:1080
    next @ core.es5.js:4503
    schedulerFn @ core.es5.js:3635
    webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:238
    webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:185
    webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.es5.js:3621
    (anonymous) @ core.es5.js:3912
    webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:392
    webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:142
    webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.es5.js:3844
    onHandleError @ core.es5.js:3912
    webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:396
    webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:158
    _loop_1 @ zone.js:702
    api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:711
    drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:610
    Promise resolved (async)
    scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:585
    webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:414
    webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:236
    webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:256
    scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:871
    ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:981
    webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ core.es5.js:4537
    webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ core.es5.js:4522
    ../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e863d796c3f68ad142cb:54
    0 @ main.bundle.js:391
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e863d796c3f68ad142cb:54
    webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap e863d796c3f68ad142cb:25
    (anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1**
```

Comment: I think this error throwing was an oversight. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7253). In any case, beta.12 will completely deprecate `md-` and the whole shakeup will be fixed. I believe providing the compatibility token is a necessary step in beta.11 if you opt for making the switch to `mat-`

Comment: Thanks for the link. That clarifies things.

Comment: Just to confirm that the release of beta12 today has fixed this problem and the error no longer occurs so you don't have to import the NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode module.